# CSS table styling and positioning

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a question regarding the styling and positioning of a table. I have created a 2 columned table with a number of rows and I want it to "fit" into my background image. 
Because this is rather vague explanation of the situation I've included this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbbu6/3).

In this fiddle you should see the table + the background image and I hope it makes sense that the table items should go in between the lines that are part of the particular background.

I've tried styling the td element with attributes like

```
  td {
  height: 20% ; 
  }
```

or

```
 td {
 cellpadding: ... ;
 cellspacing: ... ;
 }
```

(Don't know if these are even CSS attributes that I can use here)

but I just can not seem to get the table elements in the right place.
Anyone who could help me out or someone who could offer me some good information to do it on my own?

Comment: The respective corresponding CSS properties to use are `padding` and `border-spacing`.

Comment: You can start be closing your A tags.

Comment: @BoltClock: thank you, working with these properties right now so I'm hoping to fix the problem on my own.

Comment: @Diodeus: You're absolutly right about that. I always use the w3c Markup Validation Service so I would have found out afterwards, but thank you anyway!

Comment: Or you could use background-size:417px 186px to make the image fit the table :) You can also try http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp. Maybe you can find something there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use tables for layouts. In this case it makes sense to use a list:

```
<div class="news"> <!--News-->
    <ul>
        <li><label>Friday 9-September-2011</label><a href="/news/items/090911_item1.html">item 1</a></li>
        <li><label>Friday 9-September-2011</label><a href="/news/items/090911_item2.html">item 2</a></li>
        <li><label>Friday 9-September-2011</label><a href="/news/items/090911_item3.html">item 3</a></li>                        
    </ul>

</div> <!-- / News -->
```

CSS:

```
.news ul {
    float:right;
    background-image: url('http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/3368/newsbg.png');
    width: 417px ;
    height: 186px ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top:55px;
}

.news li {    
    height:38px; 
}

.news label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:230px;
}

.news a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:160px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Did not considered this approach! Thank you very much and indeed this looks to me as a better way to achieve my goal here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be doing it that way. Why don't you just take out ">>>" out of the image, save it as it's own image, and then include it either inline in the html (i.e. ) or as a background image of one of rows (centered of course). Then make the table header text and style it appropriately.

Comment: How would this not stack them on top of each other. If you add the image on the table rows (which will all be the same width) and set background-position:center; would that not put them "on top" of each other?

Answer (score 0):

You should find the right padding-top and padding-bottom for the cells, or just apply a fixed height to all of them.